# CRM 2011 - Custom View in Sitemap, makes the "Outlook Client"-configuration corrupt

Tags: redirect, sitemap, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, ampersand

When I add a subarea to my sitemap to show some custom views, i'm getting an error while trying to configurate (install) the "Outlook Client". Everything works fine in the "Web Client" of CRM 2011.  Below you can see the subarea I've used :

```
<SubArea Id="new_vendorsx" Url="/_root/homepage.aspx?etn=contact&amp;viewid=%7b2C598CB7-2E3F-DE11-8035-0050569A36D3%7d&amp;viewtype=1039">
  <Titles>
    <Title LCID="1033" Title="Vendors" />
  </Titles>
</SubArea>
```

With further investigation I can see that "&" is the problem.  When I'm putting "http://www.google.be" everything seems to work correctly for both "Outlook" & "Web"...  If I simply put "&" I can't import the customizations!

Has anyone be able to get passed this error?  I've tried to put an "RedirectPage.html" page between it, where the page redirects to the **/_root/homepage.aspx?etn=contact&viewid=%7b2C598CB7-2E3F-DE11-8035-0050569A36D3%7d&viewtype=1039** , but it gave throws me a record not found error in CRM. Also you should know that you can't access the page with **http://myURL/ORG/_root/homepage.aspx?etn=contact&viewid=%7b2C598CB7-2E3F-DE11-8035-0050569A36D3%7d&viewtype=1039**...

The code i've used in my "RedirectPage.html" is :

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Redirect Page</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function RedirectPage() {
                window.location = "../_root/homepage.aspx?etn=contact&amp;viewid=%7b2C598CB7-2E3F-DE11-8035-0050569A36D3%7d&amp;viewtype=1039";
            }
        </SCRIPT></HEAD>
<BODY onload="RedirectPage();"></BODY></HTML>
```

The page resides in the "ISV"-folder in the "CRMWEB".  I've done this just for testing :)

To put it simple => Has anyone found a way to show a custom view while clicking an item in the sitemap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have found a work around already, but this is what I did.

1) Make sure that the URL resolves fine by itself.  So login to your CRM and open a new tab.  Copy the full URL ex  "https://x.crm.dynamics.com/_root/homepage..."

2a) Instead of using a file in the ISV folder, create it as a web resource.

2b) Test the web resource by itself and make sure it shows the grid

3) Point to the web resource from you sitemap.